# Programmatically save a vcf to contacts in Android without opening Contacts app

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to programmatically save a VCF (I have both the file and the string) into the Android Contacts, without having to open up the Contacts app (or any third party app). However, all the examples I can find use an Intent to fire up the Contacts app with the VCF info.

Is there any way to directly push the data into the ContactsProvider from the VCF (other than just parsing the VCF data manually and adding it to a raw contact)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to read VCF file data and using ContentProvider you can store the contact. The library link is https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

Comment: I've got the library but I'm unsure of what method to use to convert the VCF to a Contact.

Comment: @PratikThaker Basically VCF files are in XML format. So, go with XML format decoding.